# How to implement Anti-CSRF method?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have created a ASP.NET project and I want to implement Anti-CSRF method in my project. How to do that?

Comment: I would start by [reading the official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to include a secure random token with ever request such that it cannot be guessed before hand by an attacker.

OWASP recommends you use :-

> We recommend token based CSRF defense (either stateful/stateless) as a
>   primary defense to mitigate CSRF in your applications. Only for highly
>   sensitive operations, we also recommend a user interaction based
>   protection (either re-authentication/one-time token, detailed in
>   section 6.5) along with token based mitigation.

It goes into detail [here](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md)

You also mention it's a .net application.ASP.NET core already already has in-built protection.The details of which are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1)